# RecyclerView: sets Alpha to all my ImageViews instead of specific

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

From a List(Cscore) I'm retriving a certain value called "currentscore"; I'm using this value to set the line between images that are going to be fully visible and images with an alpha set to 0.5f

For Example:

```
// CurrentScore = 4 

Item 0: alpha 1 
....
Item 4: alpha 1
Item 5: alpha 0.5f 
...
```

I'm doing this with a RecyclerView with the Adapter:

```
class ImageAdapter(var mList: MutableList<out Cscore>, var pos: Int) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ItemViewHolder> () {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        var view = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.img_layout, parent, false)
        return ItemViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var data = mList[pos]
        for (i in 0..data.maxscore) {
            Picasso.get().load(data.imgurl).into(holder?.currentImage)
            if(i>= data.currentscore) {
                holder?.currentImage.alpha = 0.5f
                }

        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mList.size

    }

 class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {
        var currentImage: ImageView = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.ImageView)!!

    }
}
```

with this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem here lays in between this lines of code:

```
if(i>= data.currentscore) {
    holder?.currentImage.alpha = 0.5f
}
```

I end up having all my ImageViews set to alpha = 0.5f and not only the items after my given limit (currentscore).

Why is this happening?

Comment: possibly a different type comparison? maybe your data.currentscore is a String while i is Int, therefore the comparison is allways true

Comment: @javierCuervas currentscore is an Integer, checked that already

Comment: `RecyclerView` is reusing the views. Try to add `alpha=1.0f` before checking the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but can you try the code below?

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {

    var data = mList[position]
    var currentScore = mList[pos].currentscore

    Picasso.get().load(data.imgurl).into(holder?.currentImage)
    if(position < currentScore) {
        holder?.currentImage.alpha = 1
    } else {
        holder?.currentImage.alpha = 0.5f
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for that edit behaviour, I rewrite my comment: this one solved it! May I ask a related question: If I'm having 2 lines of items with my Adapter with a limit (7) / line for the spanCount: `imagesrow.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext,7, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));` . After having 2 lines of images, I'm loosing the "center_horizontal" propriety inside my adapter. Can I fix that after feeding the adapter somehow?

Comment: Honestly, I think it will be better to raise a new question. This way, you can include more info about the layout and the GridLayout. You can also include screenshots as well. I think it will be better

Comment: Ok :) Thank you sir for solving my problem, half day thrown away over this problem -.-